# Google App Engine Python - Pass ProjectID to NDB Client Library?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I am new with the Google App Engine. I am building an app in Standard Environment and would like to know how to pass the ProjectID to the Python NDB Client Library, in the same way that:

```
# Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import datastore

# Instantiates a client
datastore_client = datastore.Client('my_project_id')
```

but using the ndb:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
```

Is there any related method in the library or is it just possible to include in the .yaml file?:

```
application: "my_project_id"
version: 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using GAE standard then you don't need to use `from google.cloud import datastore`.  That library allows people to access the datastore from other environments, such as GCE.  Datastore is built in to GAE standard through NDB.

For GAE standard, you shouldn't need the application name anywhere in your code, not even in the app.yaml file.  You specify the app name when you deploy with the `gcloud` command.

The old GUI tool need the app name in app.yaml but the current `gcloud` tools don't use it anymore.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I just realized that is the same with `cloudstorage`. I don't need to use `from google.cloud import storage` as long as I use the GAE, since it is built directly into the App Engine.